# Static linking libc++ clang

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, clang++, libc++

I trying to link statically the standard library libc++ (https://libcxx.llvm.org/) in Linux (Arch using this AUR https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libc%2B%2B/) using Clang.

I get the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++`

The error is independent from the code, it appears even in a "Hello World".

If I remove the `-static` option it compiles (and links) and the generated executable works.

I don't want to use libstdc++ (I have my reasons not to please not focus the discussion in this) and the linking must be static (it's a requirement).

I'm perfectly aware that it's difficult to debug this stuff without having access to the machine where it happens. However, it happens it two different machines (both with Arch) so maybe it's something I'm forgetting about.

What I have tried so far is explained here (https://releases.llvm.org/7.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/UsingLibcxx.html)

The basic command that shoud work it's the following
`clang++ -static -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -lc++abi`

Comment: The error is `cannot find -lc++`. The linker is looking for a file `libc++.a`. Do you have such a file on your system?

Answer (score 1):

That will be because you do not have a static `libc++` (i.e. `libc++.a`) installed
on your system. Archlinux defaulted to not installing static libraries [5 years ago](https://www.archlinux.org/todo/remove-static-libraries/),
so it will be challenging for you to perform fully static linkages. You will
have to make your own static builds of all dependent libraries, recursively.

Comment: for libc++ it's rather easy though... you could even hack it into the libc++ PKGBUILD and add a libc++-static subpackage

Comment: It's exactly that. Can you explain me how to build the libraries statically? I've tried to modify the PKGBUILD but I've not been able to accomplish it.

Comment: @o3305502 You can't ask [new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in comments on SO. See [makepkg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/makepkg) + [man makepkg](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/makepkg.8.html)
+ [man makepkg.conf](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/makepkg.conf.5.html) -> `OPTIONS=...staticlibs...`